# Dispute the designation of a question as off topic?

Tags: discussion, support

What is the basis and process for disputing the designation of a question as off topic here?

I'm wondering particularly about this question: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/75736/why-no-mizrachi-chief-rabbi

. . . but also generally.

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/26070

Comment: related http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1928/759

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things you can do in the general case:

- First, edit to address any outstanding comments.  Usually these are requests for clarification or to narrow down a broad scope.  If a question seems to be seeking *p'sak*, there might be comments asking that it be depersonalized.  Note that the close notice itself also includes some explanation and links.
- Try to get it reopened in the review queue.  If a question receives a reopen vote, or is on hold (not closed) and is edited, it's automatically sent to the review queue.  In [this case](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/26070) the reviewers voted to leave closed.
- Bring it up here on meta.  Post a question asking that it be reopened, or for further explanation for why it was closed.  Explain why you think it should be reopened.
- Ask for input in chat.